# How to use OpenGL without a window manager in Linux?

Tags: linux, opengl, linux-from-scratch

I've just finished the LFS book and my Linux system is working right now. I want to use OpenGL to display graphics on the screen, while the only installed package right now are those described on http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/stable/chapter03/packages.html.

I don't want to install something like Gnome, KDE or X.org. Instead, I want to use OpenGL directly from my software. Is this possible, and how can I do this? Or is it just as easy (I don't think so :'p) as writing an OpenGL application which runs full screen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to install Gnome or KDE. These are used to managed windows, and you can launch graphical applications without having a window manager.

Therefore, you'll have to install a X server. The X server is responsible of drawing things on your screen. Without X server, you can't launch graphical applications.

Once X has been installed, launch it, export your `DISPLAY` environment variable, and the rest is like writing an OpenGL application which runs full screen :-)

Comment: Thanks =D Didn't know it was so easy.

Comment: `Without X server, you can't launch graphical applications` well "technically" you can use stuff like fbdev to avoid using an X Server. *edit* sorry didn't see how old this answer was, the question got bumped

Answer (score 3):

**`kmscube` DRM example**

https://github.com/robclark/kmscube

This is possibly the most popular demo available, it uses OpenGL and EGL.

Unfortunately, the Ubuntu 18.04 package with NVIDIA proprietary drivers it does not work for me after going into Ctrl + Alt + F3:

```
drmModeGetResources failed: Invalid argument
failed to initialize legacy DRM
```

bug report: https://github.com/robclark/kmscube/issues/12

But I did get it working [on emulator](https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/tree/975ce0723ee3fa1fea1766e6683e2f3acb8558d6#kmscube).

It takes over the entire display, and shows a colorful spinning cube.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Pygame as well to create custom launch UI. Also try looking at Wayland compositor as it has replaced XServer in verisons like Fedora and Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the **[SRM library (Simple Rendering Manager)](https://github.com/CuarzoSoftware/SRM)**, which is a C library designed for rendering using OpenGL ES 2.0 within a KMS/DRM context. One of its significant advantages is that it streamlines all DRM/KMS configurations for you. Additionally, it facilitates the sharing of OpenGL textures between GPUs in a multi-GPU setup from a single allocation.

Here's a basic example of how to use it:

```
#include <SRMCore.h>
#include <SRMDevice.h>
#include <SRMConnector.h>
#include <SRMConnectorMode.h>
#include <SRMListener.h>

#include <SRMList.h>
#include <SRMLog.h>

#include <GLES2/gl2.h>

#include <math.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

float color = 0.f;

/* Opens a DRM device */
static int openRestricted(const char *path, int flags, void *userData)
{
    SRM_UNUSED(userData);

    // Here something like libseat could be used instead
    return open(path, flags);
}

/* Closes a DRM device */
static void closeRestricted(int fd, void *userData)
{
    SRM_UNUSED(userData);
    close(fd);
}

static SRMInterface srmInterface =
{
    .openRestricted = &openRestricted,
    .closeRestricted = &closeRestricted
};

static void initializeGL(SRMConnector *connector, void *userData)
{
    SRM_UNUSED(userData);

    /* You must not do any drawing here as it won't make it to
     * the screen. */

    SRMConnectorMode *mode = srmConnectorGetCurrentMode(connector);

    glViewport(0, 
               0, 
               srmConnectorModeGetWidth(mode), 
               srmConnectorModeGetHeight(mode));

    // Schedule a repaint (this eventually calls paintGL() later, not directly)
    srmConnectorRepaint(connector);
}

static void paintGL(SRMConnector *connector, void *userData)
{
    SRM_UNUSED(userData);

    glClearColor((sinf(color) + 1.f) / 2.f,
                 (sinf(color * 0.5f) + 1.f) / 2.f,
                 (sinf(color * 0.25f) + 1.f) / 2.f,
                 1.f);

    color += 0.01f;

    if (color > M_PI*4.f)
        color = 0.f;

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    srmConnectorRepaint(connector);
}

static void resizeGL(SRMConnector *connector, void *userData)
{
    /* You must not do any drawing here as it won't make it to
     * the screen.
     * This is called when the connector changes its current mode,
     * set with srmConnectorSetMode() */

    // Reuse initializeGL() as it only sets the viewport
    initializeGL(connector, userData);
}

static void pageFlipped(SRMConnector *connector, void *userData)
{
    SRM_UNUSED(connector);
    SRM_UNUSED(userData);

    /* You must not do any drawing here as it won't make it to
     * the screen.
     * This is called when the last rendered frame is now being
     * displayed on screen.
     * Google v-sync for more info. */
}

static void uninitializeGL(SRMConnector *connector, void *userData)
{
    SRM_UNUSED(connector);
    SRM_UNUSED(userData);

    /* You must not do any drawing here as it won't make it to
     * the screen.
     * Here you should free any resource created on initializeGL()
     * like shaders, programs, textures, etc. */
}

static SRMConnectorInterface connectorInterface =
{
    .initializeGL = &initializeGL,
    .paintGL = &paintGL,
    .resizeGL = &resizeGL,
    .pageFlipped = &pageFlipped,
    .uninitializeGL = &uninitializeGL
};

static void connectorPluggedEventHandler(SRMListener *listener, SRMConnector *connector)
{
    SRM_UNUSED(listener);

    /* This is called when a new connector is avaliable (E.g. Plugging an HDMI display). */

    /* Got a new connector, let's render on it */
    if (!srmConnectorInitialize(connector, &connectorInterface, NULL))
        SRMError("[srm-basic] Failed to initialize connector %s.",
                 srmConnectorGetModel(connector));
}

static void connectorUnpluggedEventHandler(SRMListener *listener, SRMConnector *connector)
{
    SRM_UNUSED(listener);
    SRM_UNUSED(connector);

    /* This is called when a connector is no longer avaliable (E.g. Unplugging an HDMI display). */

    /* The connnector is automatically uninitialized after this event (if initialized)
     * so calling srmConnectorUninitialize() is a no-op. */
}

int main(void)
{
    SRMCore *core = srmCoreCreate(&srmInterface, NULL);

    if (!core)
    {
        SRMFatal("[srm-basic] Failed to initialize SRM core.");
        return 1;
    }

    // Subscribe to Udev events
    SRMListener *connectorPluggedEventListener = srmCoreAddConnectorPluggedEventListener(core, &connectorPluggedEventHandler, NULL);
    SRMListener *connectorUnpluggedEventListener = srmCoreAddConnectorUnpluggedEventListener(core, &connectorUnpluggedEventHandler, NULL);

    // Find and initialize avaliable connectors

    // Loop each GPU (device)
    SRMListForeach (deviceIt, srmCoreGetDevices(core))
    {
        SRMDevice *device = srmListItemGetData(deviceIt);

        // Loop each GPU connector (screen)
        SRMListForeach (connectorIt, srmDeviceGetConnectors(device))
        {
            SRMConnector *connector = srmListItemGetData(connectorIt);

            if (srmConnectorIsConnected(connector))
            {
                if (!srmConnectorInitialize(connector, &connectorInterface, NULL))
                    SRMError("[srm-basic] Failed to initialize connector %s.",
                             srmConnectorGetModel(connector));
            }
        }
    }

    while (1)
    {
        /* Udev monitor poll DRM devices/connectors hotplugging events (-1 disables timeout).
         * To get a pollable FD use srmCoreGetMonitorFD() */

        if (srmCoreProccessMonitor(core, -1) < 0)
            break;
    }

    /* Unsubscribe to DRM events
     *
     * These listeners are automatically destroyed when calling srmCoreDestroy()
     * so there is no need to free them manually.
     * This is here just to show how to unsubscribe to events on the fly. */

    srmListenerDestroy(connectorPluggedEventListener);
    srmListenerDestroy(connectorUnpluggedEventListener);

    // Finish SRM
    srmCoreDestroy(core);

    return 0;
}
```

1. Start by creating an **[SRMCore](https://cuarzosoftware.github.io/SRM/group___s_r_m_core.html)** instance.
2. Then, iterate through each **[SRMDevice](https://cuarzosoftware.github.io/SRM/group___s_r_m_device.html)** (GPU). Each GPU has a list of **[SRMConnectors](https://cuarzosoftware.github.io/SRM/group___s_r_m_connector.html)** (displays).
3. Initialize the connectors you want using [srmConnectorInitialize()](https://cuarzosoftware.github.io/SRM/group___s_r_m_connector.html#ga20dc529d6d584c860517c8c918a4f0f9).
4. The library creates a rendering thread for each connector, and it invokes typical OpenGL events like ***initializeGL()***, ***paintGL()***, ***resizeGL()***, etc.
5. To schedule a new repaint in a connector, use [srmConnectorRepaint()](https://cuarzosoftware.github.io/SRM/group___s_r_m_connector.html#ga1eb0d3f9a00d2b03823ecf9b9b2e663e).
6. If you need to create OpenGL textures, refer to the [SRMBuffer documentation](https://cuarzosoftware.github.io/SRM/group___s_r_m_buffer.html).

I hope you find this library useful for your specific use case.