# Can EGL application run in console mode?

Tags: opengl, egl

I want to implement an opengl application which generates images and I view the image via a webpage.

the application is intended to run on a linux server which has no display, no x windows, but with gpu.

I know that egl can use pixmap or pbuffer as render targets.

but the function eglGetDisplay worries me, it sounds like I still need to have attached display to make it work?

does egl work without display and xwindows or wayland?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23166541/2207421).

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3804065/how-to-use-opengl-without-a-window-manager-in-linux

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a recurring question. <s>TL;DR: With the current Linux graphics driver model it is impossible to use the GPU with traditional drivers without running a X server.</s> If the GPU is supported by KMS+DRM+DRI you can do it. *(EDIT:) Also in 2016 Nvidia finally introduced truly headless OpenGL support in their drivers through EGL.*

---

The long story is, that technically GPUs are perfectly capable of rendering to an offscreen buffer without a display being attached or a graphics server running. However due to the history of graphics driver and environment development <s>this is not possible, yet</s> *has not been possible for a long time*. The assumption back then (when graphics was first introduced to Linux) was: "The graphics device is there to deliver a picture to a screen." That a graphics card could be used as an accelerating coprocessor was not even a figment of an idea.

Add to this, that until a few years ago, the Linux kernel itself had no idea how to talk to graphics devices (other than a dumb framebuffer somewhere in the system's address space). The X server was what talked to GPUs, so you needed that to run. And the first X server developers made the assumption that there is a person between keyboard and chair.

---

So what are your options:

Short term, if you're using a NVidia GPU: <s>Just start an X server. You don't need a full blown desktop environment. You can even save yourself the trouble of starting a window manager. Just have the X server claim the VT and being active.</s> *There is now support for headless OpenGL contexts through EGL in the Nvidia drivers.*

If you're using an AMD or Intel GPU you can talk directly to it. Either through EGL or using KMS (Google for something called `kmscube`, when trying it, make sure you switch away from your X server to a text VT first, otherwise you'll crash the X server). I've not tried it yet, but it should be possible to adjust the `kmscube` example that it uses the GPU to render into an offscreen buffer, without switching the VT to graphics mode or have any graphics output on the display framebuffer at all.

Comment: I'm curious, how much of this is still valid 2 years later?

Comment: @VladFiroiu: For a little bit over a year now the NVidia drivers support headless, X-less operation https://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/egl-eye-opengl-visualization-without-x-server/ however it should be noted that this is kind of proprietary. Regarding the OSS drivers you can use what I described in the very last paragraph.

Comment: Your answer is contradictory — in TL;DR you're saying it's impossible, but then in the last paragraph you're saying it's possible with EGL *(which btw supported by NVidia too)*.

Comment: @Hi-Angel: I wrote the answer originally 3 years ago. At that time it was not possible, because everything rested upon Xorg back then. A lot of things have changed since then and I amended my answer to cover the APIs that have become available ever since: NVidia's drivers added off-screen EGL support and got added a wrapper to play nicely with KMS/DRM.

Answer (score 0):

As datenwolf told u can create a frame buffer without using x with AMD and intel GPU. since iam using AMD graphics card with EGL and iam able to create a frame buffer and iam drawing on it.with Mesa Library by configuring without x u can achieve.